# Can't get event from chartjs-annotation-plugin on mouseenter

Tags: chart.js

I've tried to implement a function where i require the event from the mouse-enter-event. I don't think I've done anything wrong in my code I'm simply not getting the event parameter from the enter callback.

What i expect to happen is that i get the event from

`enter: (ctx, e) => console.log(e)`

[chartjs-annotation-doc](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/guide/interaction.html):
[image]

My Code:
https://jsfiddle.net/nf95tLm6/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the annotation plugin because if you build the current master and use that as a source it works fine.

So you will have to wait until a new version of the lib is released